# How to return True if two-dimensional array in python has at least one True

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array, boolean

I'm trying to write a code which checks if 2D-array (consists of only boolean) has at least one True and return True if there is at least one True.

I tried using `all()` function but couldn't come up with a solution. I assume what I need is opposite of what `all()` function does.

```py
>>> array1 = [[True, False], [False, False]]
>>> all([all(row) for row in array1)
False # This should be True
>>> array2 = [[False, False], [False, False]]
>>> all([all(row) for row in array2)
False # This is correct but this and array with all True is only working case.
```

For `array1 = [[True, False], [False, False]]`, I expect the output to be `True` since there is one `True` at `array1[0][0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def has_true(arr):
    return any(any(row) for row in arr)

In [7]: array1 = [[True, False], [False, False]]

In [8]: array2 = [[False, False], [False, False]]

In [9]: has_true(array1)
Out[9]: True

In [10]: has_true(array2)
Out[10]: False
```

this answer is using generators so it will return upon finding the first True value without running over the whole matrix. in addition it will use O(1) space

edit: removed unnecessary code

Comment: Thanks! This what I came up after seeing your code; `any([any(row) for row in array])`. It would be great if you could tell me this is an alternative way.

Comment: I will edit my post, your approach is correct but it should use generators

Answer (score 0):

use any() instead of all(). all() return true if all items in an iterable object are true.
any() Returns True if any item in an iterable object is true.

Answer (score 0):

A much shorter approach is to chain the lists together using [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) and apply `any` on them

```
from itertools import chain

def has_true(arr):
    return any(chain(*arr))

print(has_true([[True, False], [False, False]]))
print(has_true([[False, False], [False, False]]))
```

The output will be

```
True
False
```